# Windows 7 does not remembers my ISP address

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x86.

The problem is that every time I have to type my ISP for the connection it does not remembers my username & password, but previously Windows remembered the login data.  After every reboot I have to do the same thing again and again.

Comment: ISP stand for Internet service provider. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Are you connecting to your ISP address through a web browser? If so, which one?

Comment: Strange, there was a problem just like this using the later editions of the Windows 7 RC but it was fixed in the release. Are you using the released edition of Windows 7?